# Using Ajax to change shortcode IDs on page in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I have a custom PHP page in WordPress and need to display buttons connected to a map plugin's shortcode. Each button needs to change the map displayed on the page. The Ajax action is working, but only displays the map's ID, not the full shortcode.

I found a similar post here on StackOverflow doing something similar with Contact Form 7 shortcodes.

Javascript used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
                $('.button-map').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl, //global variable provided by WP
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            'action': 'get_map_frame',
                            'map_id': $(this).data('id')
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#map_area').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Ajax Call in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_map_frame', 'get_map_frame');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_map_frame', 'get_map_frame' );
function get_map_frame() {
    if (isset($_GET['map_id'])) {
        $map_id = (int) $_GET['map_id'];
        echo do_shortcode('[cspm_main_map id="' . $map_id . '"]');
    }
    exit();
}
```

On-page code HTML:

```
<div class="w-col w-col-12">
<div class="column-29 w-col w-col-3">
<div><a duplicate="fp-link-1" href="#" class="button-map stu w-button" data-id="5425">Dining and Drinks</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column-30 w-col w-col-3">
<div>
<a duplicate="fp-link-1" href="#" class="button-map stu w-button" data-id="5695">Entertainment and Transportation</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column-30 w-col w-col-3">
<div>
<a duplicate="fp-link-1" href="#" class="button-map stu w-button" data-id="5697">Shopping</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column-30 w-col w-col-3">
<div>
<a duplicate="fp-link-1" href="#" class="button-map stu w-button" data-id="5698">Pets and Parks</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="map_area"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is each button pulls up its individual map associated with the map ID. Currently when the button is clicked it only returns the actual map ID on the page, but not the rest of the shortcode to display the map intended.

http://aopmap.villagegreenmarketingservices.com/test123/

Comment: check browser console, its giving `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: @devpro I think this may be as you don't have JQuery loaded?

Comment: @DanClarke: i am checking this http://aopmap.villagegreenmarketingservices.com/test123/

Comment: @devpro Ah my mistake I thought you had loaded on a dev site. I'm assuming this could be that they need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: maybe...  ... . .

Comment: I'm sorry to sound ignorant here, but limited coding knowledge. Are you suggesting I change all the $ to JQuery or just a particular section of the code?

Comment: Hey @D.j.Davis, if I recall correctly WordPress's jQuery can be accessed using `jQuery()` rather than `$()`, if you change all instances to `jQuery` instead, give that a go?